# difference between output of async and mapAsync AKKA streams

Tags: asynchronous, akka, akka-stream

I am comparing the difference between `mapAsync` and `async`

```
object Demo3 extends App{

  implicit val system       = ActorSystem("MyDemo")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  private val ec             = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10))

  private def test(a:Int) ={
    println(s"Flow A : ${Thread.currentThread().getName()}" )
     Future(println(a+1))(ec)
  }

  Source(1 to 10).mapAsync(10)(test).to(Sink.ignore).run()

}
```

Output

```
    Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2
    2
    Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2
    3
    Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2
    Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2
    4
    Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2
    5
    Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2
    6
    Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2
    7
    Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2
    8
    Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2
    9
    Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2
    10
    11
```

Why dispite of parallelism to 10 it shows one name of thread. Is it not running asynchonously?
When I replace it with line `Source(1 to 100).map(test).async.to(Sink.ignore).run()` ,
Does `mapAsync` and`async`uses single thread everytime?

output

```
    Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
    2
    Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
    3
    Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
    4
    Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
    5
    Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
    6
    Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
    7
    Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
    8
    Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
    9
    Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
    10
    Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
    11
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `test`, the `println` that prints the thread ID is executed outside of the future, therefore it's executed synchronously.  The code inside the future will get executed on a thread of the `ExecutionContext` (in this case the actor system's dispatcher).  It's worth noting that some parallel execution happened: the thread print for `a = 4` happened before the `a + 1` print for `a = 3`.

If you move the thread `println` into the future, that `println` will execute asynchronously:

```
Future {
  println(s"Flow A : ${Thread.currentThread().getName()}")
  println(a+1)
}(ec)
```

Note that in your test code, you're not likely to see much parallel execution anyway: the amount of work involved in spawning the future is close to the amount of work done in the future (even with the second print in the future), so the spawned futures often complete before the next future can spawn.

`mapAsync` can best be thought of as synchronously calling code which returns a future (the future may or may not be completed at the time it's returned) and stores that future in a buffer of size `parallelism`.  When a future in that buffer completes successfully, the value it completed with is emitted and the slot in the buffer frees up, allowing `mapAsync` to demand another element (I'm technically describing `mapAsyncUnordered` because it's simpler: `mapAsync` won't emit until every future created prior to the completed one has successfully completed and emitted; I don't actually know off the top of my head if a later element completing opens up a slot in the buffer or not).  Whether this actually results in parallelism depends on the particulars of the future and how it's completed (e.g. if the future is an ask of the same actor every time, the effective parallelism is unlikely to ever be more than 1).

`async` probably should have been called `stageBoundary` or something similar in my opinion, precisely because it often leads people to think that `mapAsync` and `map(...).async` have much if anything in common. `async` is a signal to the `Materializer` that the stages between the previous `async` and this `async` should not be fused with the stages after the `async`.  In the usual `ActorMaterializer`, fused stages execute in a single actor.  This has the advantage of eliminating the overhead of transferring elements from stage to stage, at the cost of limiting, in general, the number of elements executing in a fused stage to 1.  There's an implicit buffer between fused stages: the downstream stage will signal demand based on the empty slots in its buffer.  The two stages will process in parallel, in the sense that the (possibly fused) stage before the `async` can process an element at the same time that the (possibly fused) stage after the `async` is processing an element.  This is basically pipelined execution.

So in `Source(1 to 10).mapAsync(10)(test).to(Sink.ignore).run()` the entire stream is materialized as a single actor where, (effectively: this is a description which complies with the requirements of how streams are materialized) in a single actor (so thus all of these, except for tasks scheduled onto an `ExecutionContext`, execute synchronously, in order):

- `Sink.ignore` signals effectively unbounded demand to `mapAsync`
- `mapAsync` has 10 empty slots, so requests 10 elements from the source
- `source` emits 1
- `mapAsync` prints the current thread, creates a `Promise[Unit]`, creates a closure object which looks something like

```
new ClosureClassName { val a: Int = 1; def run(): Unit = println(a+1) }
```

and schedules a task on `ec` which will run the `run` method of the closure and complete the promise's future.  The `ec` will schedule the task on a thread for asynchronous execution according to the logic of the `ec`; meanwhile our actor saves the future in its buffer (call it `futureBuffer(0)`)

- let's say that by the time we save `futureBuffer(0)`, it's completed (with `()`, the singleton value for `Unit`), `mapAsync` emits `()` to `Sink.ignore` and clears `futureBuffer(0)`
- `Sink.ignore`, well, ignores the `()` it's received
- `source` now emits 2
- `mapAsync` executes as above, only with `a = 2` in the closure
- this time, let's say that due to the vagaries of thread scheduling, `futureBuffer(0)` (now the future for `a = 2`) hasn't yet completed, so
- `source` now emits 3
- `mapAsync` executes as above, with `a = 3` in the closure, saving the future as `futureBuffer(1)`
- now both `futureBuffer(0)` and `futureBuffer(1)` have completed, so `futureBuffer(0)`'s value is emitted to `Sink.ignore` and `futureBuffer(0)` is cleared
- `Sink.ignore` ignores the value
- `futureBuffer(1)`'s value is emitted to `Sink.ignore` and `futureBuffer(1)` is cleared
- `Sink.ignore` ignores the value

So there's been a tiny bit of parallelism through `mapAsync`: the realized degree of parallelism is essentially the number of uncompleted futures.

For `Source(1 to 100).map(test).async.to(Sink.ignore).run()` that will materialize as something like

```
Actor A (Source.map)
  ^
  |      Future[Unit] sent down, demand signal sent up
  v
Actor B (Sink.ignore)
```

Let's say that the materializer settings have a receiving buffer of 2 elements per actor.

- B: `Sink.ignore` signals effectively unbounded demand to `Actor B`
- B: `B` has 2 free slots in its buffer, so it sends a message to `Actor A` demanding 3 elements
- A: `A` passes this demand to `map`, which demands 1 element from the source
- A: source emits 1
- A: `map` prints the current thread etc. as above.  It doesn't save the resulting (possibly completed or uncompleted) future in a buffer (it doesn't have one), it emits the future to `A`
- A: `A` passes the future to `B`

From here on, `A` and `B` are processing in parallel (at least some of the time in this case, since `B` is just sending elements to the bit bucket)

- A: source emits 2; meanwhile `B` passes the future it's received to `Sink.ignore`, which ignores the future (not even caring whether the future has completed, or even whether the future failed)

and so on... once B has received three elements, it will signal demand for two more (assuming, as is likely, that the `Sink` hasn't yet finished ignoring the future and the buffer of 2 elements is empty).

It's worth noting throughout this, that an actor may change from message to message which thread it's running on (whether it does is up to the `ActorSystem`'s dispatcher), but an actor maintains a single-thread illusion: it's only ever using one thread at a time.

Answer (score 1):

The computation in your example does run in parallel, the reason why it shows the same thread is because the items from `Source(1 to 10)` are dispatched to one actor that this whole stream is run by. If you change your `test` to be say:

```
private def test(a: Int) = {
    println(s"Flow A : ${Thread.currentThread().getName}")
    Future {
      println(s"Inside future Flow A : ${Thread.currentThread().getName}")
      println(a + 1)
    }(ec)
  }
```

you will see that the computation of the code passed to `Future` is in fact executed on the threadpool:

```
Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
Inside future Flow A : pool-1-thread-1
2
Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
Inside future Flow A : pool-1-thread-2
3
Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
Inside future Flow A : pool-1-thread-3
4
Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
Inside future Flow A : pool-1-thread-4
5
Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
Inside future Flow A : pool-1-thread-5
6
Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
Inside future Flow A : pool-1-thread-6
7
Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
Inside future Flow A : pool-1-thread-7
8
Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
Inside future Flow A : pool-1-thread-8
9
Inside future Flow A : pool-1-thread-9
10
Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
Inside future Flow A : pool-1-thread-10
11
```

If you adjust your stream to add `async` and log before and after it:

```
Source(1 to 10)
    .mapAsync(10)(test)
    .wireTap(_ => println(s"after mapAsync : ${Thread.currentThread().getName}"))
    .async
    .wireTap(_ => println(s"after async : ${Thread.currentThread().getName}"))
    .to(Sink.ignore)
    .run()
```

You can observe how the parallel execution results are then dispatched by the same akka thread and also that `async` introduces an async boundary in the stream:

```
Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5
Inside future Flow A : pool-1-thread-1
2
after mapAsync : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5
Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5
after async : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5
Inside future Flow A : pool-1-thread-2
3
Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5
Inside future Flow A : pool-1-thread-3
4
Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5
Inside future Flow A : pool-1-thread-4
5
Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5
Inside future Flow A : pool-1-thread-5
6
Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5
Inside future Flow A : pool-1-thread-6
7
Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5
Inside future Flow A : pool-1-thread-7
8
Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5
Inside future Flow A : pool-1-thread-8
9
Inside future Flow A : pool-1-thread-9
10
Flow A : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5
Inside future Flow A : pool-1-thread-10
11
after mapAsync : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5
after async : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
after mapAsync : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5
after async : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
after mapAsync : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5
after async : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
after mapAsync : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5
after async : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
after mapAsync : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5
after async : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
after mapAsync : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5
after mapAsync : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5
after async : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
after mapAsync : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5
after async : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
after mapAsync : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5
after async : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
after async : MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
```